# QDockWidget Docked Save and Restore Size

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a `QMainWindow` with diferents `QDockWidgets` docked, not floating.

I want to save and restore the size of this `QDockWidgets` docked.

I use the function `QSettings` and `QMainWindow saveState()` to save the actual values.

> ```
>         # Save Actual settings
>         configuration=QSettings("RBB", "MyLaps_CRI")
>         configuration.setValue("geometry", self.saveGeometry())
>         configuration.setValue("windowState", self.saveState())
> ```

[image: Save Values - Size]

I user the funtion `QSettings` and `QMainWindow restoreState()` to restore old values.

If the `QDockWidget` are Floating, they are restore perfect in position and size.

But if the QDockWidget are Docked, they are restore perfect in position but NOT in size.

> ```
>     # Restore Setting Saved
>     settings = QSettings("RBB", "MyLaps_CRI")
>     if not settings.value("geometry") == None:
>         self.restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry"))
>     if not settings.value("windowState") == None:
>         self.restoreState(settings.value("windowState"))
> ```

[image: Restored Widget]

```
# coding = u8
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *

class Classification_Show(QWidget):   
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__()
        # Create GUI
        self.create_GUI()
        self.show()
        
    def create_GUI(self):        
        """ Create GUI"""
        # Set window size
        self.resize(1200,700)
        self.setWindowTitle('Results')
        

        # Set Colors
        palette = QPalette()
        brush = QBrush(QColor(0, 85, 255))
        brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 127))
        brush.setStyle(Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern)
        
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.ColorGroup.Active, QPalette.ColorRole.Base, brush) # afecta tabla
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.ColorGroup.Active, QPalette.ColorRole.Window, brush)
        #palette.setBrush(QPalette.Inactive, QPalette.Base, brush)
        #palette.setBrush(QPalette.Inactive, QPalette.Window, brush)
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.ColorGroup.Disabled, QPalette.ColorRole.Base, brush)
        
        brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.ColorGroup.Active, QPalette.ColorRole.WindowText, brush)
        
        self.setPalette(palette)        

        
        # Create Table View of arrivals
        self.tv_arrival=QTableView()
        self.tv_arrival.setMinimumWidth(300)
        
        
        # Create Table View of Classificatiom
        self.tv_classification=QTableView()
        self.tv_classification.setMinimumWidth(300)
        
        # If is a QMainWindow create Central Widget
        #central_widget=QWidget()
        #self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        
        # Create a Grid Layout
        layout=QGridLayout(self)
        
        # Set Font for text Rider Running
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily('Calibri')
        font.setPointSize(8)
        
        widget_rider=QWidget(self)
        layout_rider=QGridLayout(widget_rider)
        
        # Create Box to show number is running
        self.rider_running_number=QLineEdit()
        self.rider_running_number.setMaximumWidth(50)
        # Set field rider running
        self.rider_running_info=QLabel('')
        self.rider_running_info.setFont(font)
        self.rider_running_name=QLabel('Prubeas')
        self.rider_running_name.setFont(font)
        
        spacerItem = QSpacerItem(4000, 20, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)

        # Show Logo
        self.logo_to_show=QLabel('')
        icon=QPixmap('C:/Roberto/Visual_Studio_Code/Rbenet/Cyclism/IMG/logo_fcc.png')
        ico=icon.scaledToWidth(100)
        self.logo_to_show.setPixmap(ico)
        
        layout_rider.addWidget(self.rider_running_number,1,1,1,1)
        layout_rider.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        layout_rider.addWidget(self.rider_running_name,1,3,1,1)
        layout_rider.addWidget(self.rider_running_info,1,4,1,1)        
        layout_rider.addWidget(self.logo_to_show,1,5,1,1)
        
        # Set title of Table
        
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        self.lb_arrival=QLabel('Llegas')
        self.lb_arrival.setFont(font)
        self.lb_classification=QLabel('Clasificaciones')
        self.lb_classification.setFont(font)
        self.lb_ddbb_name=QLabel('Pruebas')
        
        # tables and ino in a Grid       
        layout.addWidget(widget_rider,1,1,1,4)
        layout.addWidget(self.lb_arrival,2,1,1,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.lb_classification,2,3,1,4)
        layout.addWidget(self.tv_arrival,3,1,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.tv_classification,3,3,1,4)
        layout.addWidget(self.lb_ddbb_name,4,1,1,6)
        """
        """

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Set window size
        self.resize(600,400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Save Dock Widget')

        # If is a QMainWindow create Central Widget
        central_widget=QWidget()
        #central_widget=QFrame()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        
        # Create a Grid Layout
        layout=QGridLayout(central_widget)

        self.pb_stop_crono=QPushButton('Para Crono')
        self.pb_screen_2=QPushButton('Pantalla 2')
        self.le_capture=QLineEdit('')
        self.le_capture.setEnabled(False)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_stop_crono,0,1,1,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_screen_2,0,2,1,1)
        
        self.classification_show=Classification_Show(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.classification_show,1,1,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_capture,2,1,1,1)  

        self.CreateWidgets()
        self.readSettings()
        self.show()

    def CreateWidgets(self):        
        #self.showFullScreen()

        self.firstDock_ = Dock(self, 'First')
        self.firstDock_.setObjectName('First')
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.DockWidgetArea.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.firstDock_)     

        self.secondDock_ = Dock(self, 'Second')
        self.secondDock_.setObjectName('Second')
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.DockWidgetArea.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.secondDock_)

        self.thirdDock_ = Dock(self, 'Third')
        self.thirdDock_.setObjectName('Third')
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.DockWidgetArea.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.thirdDock_)
        self.thirdDock_.setFloating(True)
        
        self.fDock_ = Dock(self, 'Fourth')
        self.fDock_.setObjectName('Fourth')       
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.DockWidgetArea.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.fDock_)
        self.fDock_.setFloating(True)

        self.fiDock_ = Dock(self, 'Fifth')
        self.fiDock_.setObjectName('Fifth')
        self.fiDock_.setFloating(True)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.DockWidgetArea.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.fiDock_)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('closing')
        settings = QSettings()
        settings.setValue('geometry',self.saveGeometry())
        settings.setValue('windowState',self.saveState())
        super(Window, self).closeEvent(event)

    def readSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings()
        self.restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry"))
        self.restoreState(settings.value("windowState"))

class Dock(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super(Dock, self).__init__(parent)                       
        #self.setGeometry(500,500,500,500)



def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setOrganizationDomain('ltd')
    app.setOrganizationName('Alg')
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamente update info

Comment: We need a *complete* MRE that is **both** minimal ***and*** reproducible. We should be able to copy, paste and run the code without any substantial modification.

Comment: @musicament I find my problem. In 'QMainWindow()' I 'resize()' the widget. If I don't resize then the restore is perfect. I don't know what I have to do with this question, delete the question, give an answer,.... (Thank you for your help)

Comment: It's up to you, now the code is reproducible (it could be more minimal, though, so please consider this for future reference: you should always try to remove *anything* that is not relevant for the question and is not required to make the code reproducible). The solution is quite simple, but it could be worth an answer, since there's no direct reference on the documentation about possible incompatibilities between `resize()` and `restoreState()`. I suggest you to try to trim down your question by shortening it and leaving only the reproducible code (try to reduce it more), then answer it.